# Add markers to an image on Android

Tags: android, maps, android-imageview, marker

So I have custom indoor map of a building as an image. It's being displayed using Image View. I have managed to add zoom function using TouchImageView custom package. However I'am struggling to add markers with some informations. Does anyone can explain to me how I can achieve this?

any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: An image view isn't really the appropriate way to do that.  You'd be better off with a custom view, so you have total control over the drawing and can just draw the markers in your onDraw.  Deriving a custom view from ImageView may work well here.

Comment: quite new to this, could explain bit more or post a link?